# SSL error with python websocket-client 0.20

Tags: python, ssl, websocket

I have a websocket client using SSL with python and and [websocket-client 0.20](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client/0.20.0).

I'm using both server- and client-side certs. One of my clients fails with the following SSL error:

> ERROR      2015-12-02 16:51:28,706 _app:206 _callback [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1242: error:1409F07F:lib(20):func(159):reason(127)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/websocket/_app.py", line 204, in _callback
>       callback(self, *args)
>   ...

The error is completely cryptic and I'm at a loss as to what to do about it, and Google is not much help. It does not seem to matter if I set CERTS_NONE in the ssl_opts or not.

What exactly is it that fails there in ssl.c?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Mostly I am interested in some insight as to what openssl is trying to tell me by the error. Then I might be able to look what to do to fix the situation.

Comment: Just googling "1409F07F". It seems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997218/why-am-i-getting-error1409f07fssl-routinesssl3-write-pending-bad-write-retr . Have a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715408/pyopenssl-ssl3-write-pendingbad-write-retry-return-self-sslobj-writedata-er

Comment: Thanks -- I'll have to see if it is the client that retries something wrong, or what.

Comment: From my understanding, you need to resend the exact same data - therefore you have to copy it in a buffer or so.

Comment: Yep. I raised this issue with websocket-client at github, we'll see if this should happen at library level or application level.